# Setting multiple values for a single property in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using neo4j 2.1.2 community edition.

My query , can I add  multiple values for single property.

Example , suppose i have a node called "11".
11 has properties called name - john, age-34, gender-m, **phone_no- 1234,5678**.
So it has two values for phone_no. So how can i create a single node with properties name,age,gender and phone_no, where phone_no shuold have 2 values.

Normally will do it as(for single phone_no),

```
CREATE (n:Person{name:'john',age:34,gender:'m', phone_no:1234})
```

So for multiple phone_no, can i do as below:

```
CREATE (n:Person{name:'john',age:34,gender:'m', phone_no:1234,5678})
```

So how can i achieve it using cypher queries?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

using `collections` []

```
CREATE (n:Person{name:'john',age:34,gender:'m', phone_no:[1234,5678]})
```

Comment: did the same thing. I;m able to add multiple values to a single property But how can i extract the phone_nos i'e., how can i get the values out of collection?

Comment: Also how can i update the property values. When i run the query `CREATE (n:Person{name:'john',age:34,gender:'m', phone_no:[1234,1111]})` (with 2nd phone_no changed). It created one more node for the 2nd time execution . But I wanted to update the phone_no without creating new node. Is it possible?

Comment: You should not really be asking a series of new questions in the comments to a (perfectly suitable) answer to your original question. Instead, if necessary, please submit new questions.

Comment: its similar as working with arrays, to return the second value simply `MATCH n(name:'john') RETURN n.phone_no[1];`. the first value in arrays is usually `[0]`, 3th `[2]`, etc